# Abaqus turn surfaces into sets

Tags: python, set, coordinates, abaqus

I've been trying to find the centers of two surfaces in my model (see photo), but don't manage to do so. They are element surfaces (faces) and there is no option in the query to find centers of element surfaces, only of element sets. Finding the center of node sets is also fine, but my node sets do not appear in the tools -> query -> mass property options.
And I can't find an option to convert my element surfaces into element sets.

What I eventually want is to find the centers of both red highlighted surfaces and draw a line between them. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your surfaces contain elements then you can always retrieve them and create a set on the base of it.

```py
m = mdb.models['myModel']
a = m.rootAssembly

es_l5_inferior_elems = a.surfaces['ES_L5INFERIOR'].elements
es_l5_inferior_elems_set = a.Set(
    name='ES_L5INFERIOR_ELEMS_SET',
    elements=es_l5_inferior_elems 
)
```

If you want to get a nodes set, I am afraid you have to loop through all the elements in `es_l5_inferior_elems` and use the `getNodes()` method of a `MeshElement` object (keeping in mind that there will be repetitions to delete).

To get the mass/volume center you can use the dedicated method [`getMassProperties()`](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch06pyo01.html#ker-assembly-getmassproperties-pyc) of the Part or rootAssembly. By the way, to use it you do not need Sets (simply give the elements/nodes array)!

```py
mass_prop = a.getMassProperties(regions=es_l5_inferior_elems)

print(mass_prop['volumeCentroid'])
print(mass_prop['centerOfMass'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I enter the code as you described, I receive the following error when I try to print the mass properties: TypeError; found MeshElement, expecting Region

Comment: Strange, for me it is working. Try explicitly creating a [region](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/pt01ch45pyo03.html)

Comment: Btw, after calling `a.surfaces['ES_L5INFERIOR'].elements` you should have the `MeshElementArray` object and not `MeshElement`: the former counts for the `Region`, the latter not. Check that you are not having an error somewhere